# Templated function can't convert 'int' to nullptr_t

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

**TL;DR:**

Why can't templated functions access the same conversions that non-templated functions can?

```
struct A {
    A(std::nullptr_t) {}
};

template <typename T>
A makeA(T&& arg) {
    return A(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

void foo() {
    A a1(nullptr); //This works, of course
    A a2(0); //This works
    A a3 = makeA(0); //This does not
}
```

---

**Background**

I'm trying to write some templated wrapper classes to use around existing types, with the goal of being drop-in replacements with minimal need to rewrite existing code that uses the now-wrapped values.

One particular case I can't get my head around is as follows: we have a class which can be constructed from `std::nullptr_t` (here called A), and as such, there's plenty of places in the code base where someone has assigned zero to an instance.

However, the wrapper cannot be assigned a zero, despite forwarding the constructors. I have made a very similar example that reproduces the issue without using an actual wrapper class - a simple templated function is sufficient to show the issue.

I would like to allow that syntax of being able to assign zero to continue to be allowed - it isn't my favourite, but minimising friction to moving to newer code is often a necessity just to get people on board with using them.

I also don't want to add a constructor that takes any int other than zero because that's very much absurd, was never allowed before, and it should continue to be caught at compile time.

If such a thing is not possible, it would satisfy me to find an explanation, because with as much as I know so far, it makes no sense to me.

This example has the same behaviour in VC++ (Intellisense seems to be OK with it though...), Clang, and GCC. Ideally a solution will also work in all 3 (4 with intellisense) compilers.

A more directly applicable example is follows:

```
struct A {
    A(){}
    A(std::nullptr_t) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    A a;
    Wrapper(const A& a):a (a) {}

    template <typename T>
    Wrapper(T&& t): a(std::forward<T>(t)){}

    Wrapper(){}
};

void foo2() {
    A a1;
    a1 = 0; // This works

    Wrapper<A> a2;
    a2 = 0; //This does not
}
```

Comment: 0 is a null pointer, (int)(0) is not

Comment: Why has the compiler decided to treat the zero as an int?

Comment: integral literal is int if it fits

Comment: "*we have a class which can be constructed from std::nullptr_t (here called A), and as such, there's plenty of places in the code base where someone has assigned zero to an instance.*" I question the design of an object that can be initialized from `nullptr`, but not from a pointer that *isn't* NULL.

Comment: Changing the line to `a1 = int(0);` works only in VC++ (and intellisense) so this is looking like the answer.

Comment: @LyndenShields: The answer to what? How does that solve your problem? It doesn't allow you to create `a1` indirectly with a literal 0.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's because we used to use pointers directly, but now we use this class that should never be initialised from a pointer, but that's initialisable from `nullptr`, because I wanted to continue to allow the ` = 0` semantics which were used quite a lot and was semantically safe to do.
Not great, but safe enough.

Comment: @NicolBolas It solves my question because it shows me why it's impossible. I haven't read your answer yet.

Comment: @Danh `0` is an `int` prvalue, not a null pointer.

Comment: @M.M I meant "can be".

Comment: @Danh You mean "can be converted to"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why has the compiler decided to treat the zero as an int?

Because it is an integer.

The literal 0 is a literal. Literals get to do funny things. String literals can be converted into `const char*` or `const char[N]`, where `N` is the length of the string + NUL terminator. The literal 0 gets to do funny things too; it can be used to initialize a pointer with a NULL pointer constant. And it can be used to initialize an object of type `nullptr_t`. And of course, it can be used to create an integer.

But once it gets passed as a parameter, it can't be a magical compiler construct anymore. It becomes an actual C++ object with a concrete type. And when it comes to template argument deduction, it gets the most obvious type: `int`.

Once it becomes an `int`, it *stops* being a literal 0 and behaves exactly like any other `int`. Not unless it is used in a `constexpr` context (like your `int(0)`), where the compiler can figure out that it is indeed a literal 0 and therefore can take on its magical properties. Function parameters are never `constexpr`, and thus they cannot partake in this.

Comment: _"Function parameters are never `constexpr`, and thus they cannot partake in this."_
Ah yes. Thank you. You gave me hope and then dashed it on the rocks.

Comment: @LyndenShields moral of the story: avoid using `0` where a null pointer is expected

Comment: And now I can point to this question when my colleagues complain :D

Answer (score 3):

See [conv.ptr]/1:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type [...]

So the integer literal `0` can be converted to a null pointer.  But if you attempt to convert some other integer value, that is not a literal,  to a pointer type then the above quote does not apply. In fact there is no other implicit conversion  from integer to pointer (since none such is listed in [conv.ptr]), so your code fails.

Note: Explicit conversion is covered by [expr.reinterpret.cast]/5.